# JavaScript not rendering in Wordpress (but works in example)

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

So I'm trying to put some Javascript code and HTML in a Wordpress Theme Topbar entered via the Custom Welcome Text box as below:

[Custom Welcome Text box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KZVd.png)

When I enter the Javascript and HTML in the Custom Welcome Text box, the code works in my website example at the time I enter the code in as below:

[Working topbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otIC8.png)

But when I save the entered Javascript and HTML in that box by pressing "Publish", the actual page shows the Javascript code in the topbar rather than rendering it as below:[non rendered Javascript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qm9h4.png)

I'm not really sure what's causing it as it renders correctly in the Welcome Text Box when entering it but not when the page actually renders.

The code I'm entering is below:

[

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

var thehours = new Date().getHours();
 var themessage;
 var day = ('02 1111 1111');
 var after = ('0411 000 000');

 if (thehours >= 9 && thehours < 17) {
  themessage = day; 

 } else if (thehours >= 17 && thehours < 24) {
  themessage = after;

 } else if (thehours >= 0 && thehours < 9) {
  themessage = after;
 }

document.getElementById('myLink').innerHTML=themessage;

var link = "tel:" + themessage.replace(/ /g, "");

document.getElementById("myLink").href=link;

</script>
```

```html
<span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:17px;">Call to Discuss <span style="font-family:Wingdings;font-size:19px;">&#41;</span>&nbsp;<a id="myLink"></a>&nbsp;<span style="font-family:Wingdings;font-size:19px;">&#41;</span> 24 Hours</span>
```

][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Nboo.png)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Just edited to add code - sorry forgot this part. As it's entered via a Wordpress interface, the "works in example" is contained in the linked image.

Comment: Wordpress is stripping those as I remember because it could be vulnerable code injected to your site. So it will be rendered as a encoded string rather than real html-tag code... better you add the relevant code to your theme directly

Answer (score 0):

It was the php function (not sure if that's the right terminology) rendering the code into text I think.

I edited the php file directly and was able to resolve the problem rather than using the Custom Welcome Text box.